# How to justify saying WLOG in this scenerio?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

The problem and my proof in question:

If $a, b, c > 0$, show that it is not possible for each of the polynomials $P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c,
 Q(x) = cx^2 + ax + b,  R(x) = bx^2 + cx + a$ to have two real roots.

*Proof*: WLOG let $a\geq b\geq c>0$. Then it follows that $c^2-4ab<0$. Thus, $Q(x)$ does not have 2 real roots.

My question is how do we justify saying WLOG in this situation. The reasoning I have built up so far seems incomplete. Here is my reasoning so far:

Clearly if we consider the two polynomials $R(x)=bx^2 + cx + a$ and $ax^2 + cx + b$ we see that the determinant, $c^2-4ab$ is the same for both. The same holds for $Q(x)$ and $P(x)$. So we have all $3!=6$ "coefficient permutations" for $a,b,$ and $c$. Therefore, we can justify substituting $a$ with $b$ or $c$ and vice verse and the problem will remain unchanged. Is there a better way of saying this? Am I wrong?

Extra: There is also an alternative proof to this problem:

Assume all given polynomials have two real roots. Then, $c^2>4ab, b^2>4ac, a^2>4bc$. Which implies the immpossible, namely that $a^2b^2c^2>64a^2b^2c^2$.

Comment: Is this `proof-verification` or `proof-explanation`? Is the proof written by you and you want to verify it or is it from somewhere else?

Comment: I would say 'WLOG $c \leq a$ and $c \leq b$'.

Comment: Alternatively, given $a, b, c > 0$, we have $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ if and only if $a + b(1/x) + c(1/x)^2 = 0$, since $0$ cannot be roots. So $P(x)$ has two zeros if and only if $\tilde{P}(x)=cx^2+bx+a$ has two zeros, and using this we can reverse the order of coefficients.

Comment: @SangchulLee:  that is a good argument, but I think it needs to be made, not just swept under the rug.

Comment: A general comment is that you should be judicious in your use of 'WLOG', because it imposes an additional burden on the reader if the WLOG is nontrivial to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WOLOG is not correct.  Because of the cyclic nature of the problem you can relabel $a,b,c$ to make $a$ the greatest.  Once you do that, there is no restriction on whether $b$ or $c$ is greater.  I would say if $a \ge b \ge c \gt 0,$ then $c^2-4ab \lt 0$ and $Q(x)$ does not have real roots.  If $a \ge c \ge b \gt 0,$ then $b^2-4ac \lt 0$ and $P(x)$ does not have real roots.

Alternately, you can make the argument SangchulLee makes in the comments to justify the reverse cyclic order.  It is a good one, but I think it should be stated.